# Can't get a simple SELECT to work

Tags: mysql, select

I have done this type of SELECT many times, but this time I can't get it to work. Any ideas, please?

```
$Name = "Dick";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $dbname, $dbpw, $dbuser);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE $Name = table.first_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$customer_id = $row['id'];
Database::disconnect();

echo "customer id = " . $customer_id;
```

Comment: @JohnConde: The "backwards" part doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't forget to [enable exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so errors are made visible. What's very peculiar here is the `Database::disconnect()` call being made, yet you've created a handle independent of that apparently.

Comment: Any error log you might want to add to your question?

Comment: You need to add quotes around $Name

Comment: It is highly discouraged to use mysqli_* functions since they are highly vulnerable (and deprecated) to SQL injections. Instead it is recommended to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @yarwest: That's incorrect.  There's nothing wrong with using `mysqli_` functions.  You're thinking of the *old* `mysql_` functions (note the lack of the letter `i`).  MySQLi is perfectly safe to use, if you use it right.  It supports prepared statements just like PDO does.

Comment: @RocketHazmat if you are right then my knowledge is outdated, I will have to look into that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really DO have a table named `table` it would be more appropriate to use back ticks around the name since the word `TABLE` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You should also use single quotes around your variable if it contains a string:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `first_name` = '$Name'";
```

Other possible reasons if the query still doesn't work for you:

1. Make sure you have the connection parameters in the right order. It should be: `mysqli_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname)`.
2. You should be using `fetch_array()` instead of `fetch_assoc()` if you expect a one row result.
3. You are mixing PROCEDURAL STYLE with Object Oriented Style when using `mysqli_connect()` instead of `mysqli()`, at the same time using `$result->` which is object oriented style. You should decide one style and stick with it.

This would be the procedural style of your query:

```
$Name = "Dick";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname); // NOTE THE CHANGED ORDER OF CONNECTION PARAMETERS!
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `first_name` = '$Name'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$customer_id = $row['id']; // YOUR CUSTOMER ID

mysqli_free_result($result); // FREE RESULT SET
mysqli_close($conn); // CLOSE CONNECTION
```

And this would be the object oriented style:

```
$Name = "Dick";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `first_name` = '$Name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$customer_id = $row['id']; // YOUR CUSTOMER ID

$result->free(); // FREE RESULT SET
$conn->close(); // CLOSE CONNECTION
```

I would recommend naming your table something else than `table` since it's a reserved word and could get you into parsing problems. The same goes with field names. More reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

More about `mysqli_fetch_array()` and differences in procedural style and object oriented style use: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thank you, all. I missed the obvious. I needed to enclose the '$Name' in single quotes. It works on PDO and mysqli now, but I will stick with PDO for security reasons. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE '$Name' = table.first_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to concat the variable like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE " . $Name . " = table.first_name";
```

Comment: That is not necessary in PHP if you use double quotes.

Comment: You're still missing quotes around your string (`$Name`).